# What is io.netty.allocator.maxOrder in Netty?

Tags: java, netty, directmemory

Please, explain what is io.netty.allocator.maxOrder in Netty!

By default it value is 11, thus I get  8192 << 11 = 16MiB per chunk
For 2 cores on Java 11 I get 4 direct arenas with 6 DirectByteBuffers each (I have memory dump).
So 16Mib x 4 arenas x 6bufs = 384Mib.

My application has transport server based on netty with hundreds of client connections sending lots of small messages (some Kbytes each message). But also my app uses direct memory for its own needs. So extra 384Mib costs too much for me.

Please, advise, can I reduce io.netty.allocator.maxOrder to value 8 without any regression in netty performance?

Comment: How about to measure difference yourself?

Comment: I had tested and there was no difference.But my tests possibly don't cover all the cases. Besides netty authors possibly had something on mind to put such default value.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you looking to understand what is `io.netty.allocator.maxOrder` or how to tune it for the stated use case? Those are separate questions and the title is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can. Just use a profiler to understand the effect here. These numbers were used based on the jemalloc paper / blog post at the point of time when writing the implementation.